# How to remove a substring in a fullstring without deleting any other element that matches the substring

Tags: python

I have 2 lists. How do I remove a substring in list2 exists in list1?

```py
list1 = ['123foo, 134foo', '124bar', '1123foo']
list2 = ['123foo', '124bar']
```

This is what I am expecting:

```py
expectedlist1 = ['134foo', '1123foo']
```

I have so far done this to find the substring in fullstring, and to remove the substring but unfortunately the result is not what I am expecting.

```py
def removesubstring(list1, list2):
    for x in range(len(list2)):
        for y in range(len(list1)):
            if search(list2[x],list1[y]):
                list1[y] = list1[y].replace(list2[x], "")
    list1= list(filter(None, list1)) #To remove the empty strings from the list
    return list1, list2
```

What I am getting after running my code:

```py
resultinglist = [', 134foo', '1']
```

The reason for not flattening the list is that the indexes of the list would change. The indexes of the list are important to maintain as they are referring another list with the same length. If there is a way to unflatten it to the original length then it is welcomed (but im not sure if its possible)

Comment: `[x for x in list1 if x not in list2]`

Comment: Look at the list, they contain strings seperated by commas

Comment: Oh so I would first "flatten" the list, and then it is back to the duplicate: `list1 = [s for s in elem.split() for elem in list1]`

Comment: @Tomerikoo If I flatten the list, I cannot 'unflatten it' to the same idexes afterwards. Its important to maintain the indexes.

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Can you [edit] the example for a more exemplary case? One where my suggestion fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For efficiency, convert `list2` to a set.
- Iterate over `list1`:

  - `split` each string on `", "` and remove elements which are in `list2`.
  - `join` back the leftover strings with `", "`
  - Add to the result list.

```py
list1 = ['123foo, 134foo', '124bar', '1123foo']
list2 = ['123foo', '124bar']

set2 = set(list2)
res = []
for s in list1:
    leftovers = [part for part in s.split(', ') if part not in set2]
    if leftovers:  # To avoid adding an empty string
        res.append(', '.join(leftovers))

print(res)
```

Gives:

```
['134foo', '1123foo']
```

Comment: Works like Magic :)